# OpenID configuration between Forgerock and AWS cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, openam, forgerock

How to configure the federation between ForgeRock OpenAM and AWS cognito using User pool?

Comment: Which of both should act as Relying Party (RP) and which is OpenID Connect Provider (OP)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.